# Git equivalent to TFS changesets

Tags: git, tfs

I'm not a Git expert, therefore this question may seem pretty basic for some - sorry.

I'm looking for an equivalent of changesets functionality in Git. The closest thing I'm seeing is STASH.

Thing is, stashing has several "functionalities" I don't like much

- they are stored in a stack fashion (that is, when you pop last item, it's deleted, can this be avoided?),
- when you create a stash it reverts your local changes (is there a way to avoid that?)

I'm looking for a way for one dev to tell another "here are my local changes, can you code review them? And by the way, can you build my changes on your side to make sure I'm no missing any files?"

Comment: Just commit and push the changes?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just looking for [branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching).

Comment: Not really. I wanted a really lighweight way to generate a set of changes so devs can ask others to code review them, for ex. You can do that with branches, but following that sample, that would entail for the reviewer looking at the code in that branch, and more importantly, pretty sure won't see the deltas to review.

Comment: @Ariel I disagree - `git diff` makes it trivial to display "change sets."

Answer (score 1):

To just apply a change from the stash without actually removing it from the stash (i.e what `pop` does after applying the changes), you can use `git stash apply`:

> apply [--index] [-q|--quiet] []
>
> Like pop, but do not remove the state from the stash list. Unlike pop,
>    may be any commit that looks like a commit created by stash
>   save or stash create.

`git stash save` runs `git reset --hard` after creating the stash, to restore the working tree state to that of the last commit. There is no option in `git stash` to avoid this.

You could either run `git stash apply` again and continue working on top of the changes or use topic or feature branches to keep track of your work.

Answer (score 0):

[Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) provides such a functionality, and it is called Patchset. Take a look at the [default workflow](http://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-patch.html) of Gerrit.